# How to solve problem with url and hyperref packages?

Tags: errors, hyperref, urls

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref} %Hyperlinks


\begin{document}

Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::type() in \url{C:\wamp\www\mysite\sites\all\modules\userpoints\userpoints_rules.rules.inc}

\end{document}
```

It returns an error. However, when I comment the third line, there's no problem. Changing the order of the second and third line doesn't help. I need the `hyperref` package somewhere else in my document, so simply deleting the third line is not an option.

How can I solve this?

Comment: All thos backslashes are treated as control sequences. Replace them with forward shlashes, don't worry, this works on windows. Also, use `\path` instead of `\url`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`url` (which is loaded automatically by `hyperref`) provides a command called `\path` which you can use.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref} %Hyperlinks

\begin{document}

Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::type() in \path{C:\wamp\www\mysite\sites\all\modules\userpoints\userpoints_rules.rules.inc}

\end{document}
```